# Is there a proper way to scale actors on the Stage?(Libgdx)

Tags: java, libgdx, screen, resolution

I'm making an android app which has Libgdx Stage handling the HUD. But how can I scale things I add to Stage?

I've tried some manipulations with Camera, Viewport, and none of the work properly. Let's say I want my ImageButton placed in the right top corner of the screen. I managed to do that manipulating with table positioning, it seems to be fine. But the problem appear when I run my app on my phone. The ImageButton positioned right but it's kinda small :-)

Thing is I want ImageButton look like on (540,800) resolution screen.
ImageButton is (65,65).
When it comes to bigger screensizes ImageButton starts to look small because it does not scale(or the viewport and camera stuff dont work well, I dont think the actual scaling is truly necessary)

Comment: To scale your HUD or everything else for different Screen sizes you need to use Viewports.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the documentation about Viewports, which is pretty clear, although a bit dated : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

If you don't need to mess with the camera, don't bother to declare one. Simply use a stage, with includes automatically an orthographic camera. If you declare an Actor within the bounds of the viewport, it should scale properly depending on the type of viewport you selected. For instance :

```
FillViewport vp = new FillViewport(800, 1280); // fills the screen, adapting itself to actual screen ratio
Stage stage = new Stage(vp);
```